# How do I make a chrome extension that will take the current webpage and upload it to my custom domain via FTP so I can view it on a phone?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ftp, web-hosting

### Overview

I am trying to make a Chrome Extension that takes the currently open html page and all its dependencies (CSS, JS) and uploads it to a custom domain via FTP. I would then be able to open it on my phone to make sure the website looks good on a phone.

Basically, I am trying to replicate the VSCode extension Live Server's functionality, but with it uploading the file to a custom domain. I know you'd normally be able to access live server's locally hosted server from a phone, but my university's internet setup doesn't seem to allow for this, hence my desire for an extension like this.

All I know about my hosting service is that it uses cPanel and supports FTP, which I assume is all I need. I can set up new FTP connections and logins. All the FTP details in the code will be hardcoded, but drawn from a separate file and .gitignored so they aren't in my commit history, which I hope is enough.

### What I've Tried & What I'm Stuck On

I have most of the chrome extension stuff figured out; The FTP transfer process is what's giving me issues.

I first tried using [chrome-app-ftp](https://github.com/MikeCostello/chrome-app-ftp), but quickly realized that was old and was running into issues, so I switched to [jsftp](https://github.com/sergi/jsftp/).

I used browserify to fix the "require" issue, and that cleared up some stuff.

I'm currently stuck on the following bug:

```
Error: TypeError: createConnection is not a function
```

I've done my research, and I do not think the error is because of an issue in my code; I believe that it is just a limitation of the tools I am using. This seems to be an issue with front-end JS not supporting the "net" module, which brings me to my question.

### My Question

How do I circumvent my lack of support for the "net" module in the front-end? Do I need to set up some sort of local back-end for this with node or something like that? I have basically zero experience with anything back-end, so I might need pointed towards what sort of back-end is best for this. I more just need to know which tech stack is best for doing this.

If additional information is necessary I'll be checking back frequently and happy to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think browser JavaScript can connect to ftp. It can connect to http/https or WebSockets servers. Extensions don't have extra APIs for that.

Comment: Extensions can launch a separate utility via [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) and send a JSON message that will be uploaded by that utility to an ftp server. You can utilize node.js for this, there are examples/libraries to facilitate nativeMessaging connection.